# Bug with Android 11 and (some) Samsung phones

Tags: multi-touch, samsung-galaxy, android-11

I’ve stumbled upon a bug about multi touch.

It seems that, from the latest Android 11 update, my app cannot get consistent coordinates inside a view.

Tested with S20+ on Samsung lab.

Let’s say i touch a view on its very top left point.
A MotionEvent is spawned and event.getX() and event.getY() returns 0.

BUT… if i press the screen with 2 finger, one in a random screen area and one on the same top-left pixel of the previous view… the latter gets

event.getX() -> 300 (circa, depending on where the View is inside the screen)
event.getY() -> 400 (same)

Is it a bug or i’m doing something wrong?
This didn’t happen with any Samsung phone with Android 10 or any non-Samsung phone

Any workaround?

Comment: If you need to handle when touching with more than one finger then you should resolve first the "pointer index", and use the corresponding getX(pointerIndex) / getY(pointerIndex) overloads. Did you tried these overloads to see if you get the right results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also received some bug reports from users of my app on the Play Store. I also found this

https://github.com/Swordfish90/Lemuroid/issues/178#issuecomment-782883990

It seems Samsung messed something up. The workaround described in the link above seems to fix the issue. I personally find this workaround very annoying and it should not be needed to build it that way. Don't know if this issue will be fixed soon from Samsung though...